# UICollectionViewCell size larger the UICollectionView size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, cell

I'm having the following runtime error: the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.

This started occuring after a implemented, insize my custom UICollectionViewCell a UISearchBar item. When I click in it the keyboard shows up and the cell are half slided to the top.,

These are my relevant code:

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

 func setupCollectionView() {
        if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            flowLayout.invalidateLayout()

        }

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView?.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView?.register(TrendingCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: trendingCellId)
        collectionView?.register(SubscriptionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: subscriptionCellId)
        collectionView?.register(MapCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: mapCellId)
        collectionView?.register(AccountCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: accountCellId)


        collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 50, 0)
        collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 50, 0)

        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true

        view.addSubview(menuBar)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: menuBar)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(50)]", views: menuBar)

        menuBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  (collectionView?.bottomAnchor)!).isActive = true


    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 50)
    }

}

class MapCell:  UICollectionViewCell{

    let topContainer: TopContainerView = {
        let v = TopContainerView()

        return v
    }()


    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        backgroundColor = .brown

        topContainer.setupView()
        addSubview(topContainer)

        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(40)]", views: topContainer)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: topContainer)

        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: topContainer, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: topContainer, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.endEditing(true)

    }}

class TopContainerView: UIView {

    func setupView(){
        backgroundColor = .yellow


        addSubview(searchField)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: searchField)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]-40-|", views: searchField)

        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchField, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 5))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchField, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 5))
    }

    let searchField: UISearchBar = {
        let sf = UISearchBar()
        sf.placeholder = "Search"

        return sf
    }()

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.endEditing(true)

    }}
```

Does any one have any ideia?